# Java - Connect to a virtual machine instead of Local Host using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, p2p

I made a program to do simple operations in Local Host, such as type a number and a power, calculate it in another class and send it back, but I want to know how to do this with a virtual machine so I can obtain data from the client, here's my code for the virtual client and the connection to it:

```
package clientedatos;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ClienteDatos
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
int Valor, Potencia;
Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Capture un valor que sera elevado a una potencia");
Valor=Sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Capture la potencia");
Potencia=Sc.nextInt();
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
ObjectInputStream ois = null;
Socket s = null;
try
{
// instancio el server con la IP y el PORT
s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5432);
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
// envio un nombre
oos.writeObject(Valor+","+Potencia);
long a=System.currentTimeMillis();
// recibo la respuesta (el saludo personalizado)
String ret = (String)ois.readObject();
long b=System.currentTimeMillis();
String[] respuesta = ret.split(",");
long Latencia = (a-b)-Integer.parseInt(respuesta[1]);
// muestro la respuesta que envio el server
System.out.println(respuesta[0]);
System.out.println("La latencia es: "+Latencia);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
if( ois != null ) ois.close();
if( oos != null ) oos.close();
if( s != null ) s.close();
}
}
}
```

And here's the code for the Server:

```
package datosclientes;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
public class ServerDatos
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
ObjectInputStream ois = null;
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
Socket s = null;
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5432);
while( true )
{
try
{
// el ServerSocket me da el Socket
s = ss.accept();
// informacion en la consola
System.out.println("Se conectaron desde la IP: "
+s.getInetAddress());
// enmascaro la entrada y salida de bytes
ois = new ObjectInputStream( s.getInputStream() );
oos = new ObjectOutputStream( s.getOutputStream() );
// leo el nombre que envia el cliente
long A=System.currentTimeMillis();
String ValorStr = (String)ois.readObject();
String[] input = ValorStr.split(",");
int Valor = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
int Potencia = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
// armo el saludo personalizado que le quiero enviar
for(int i = 1;i<Potencia; i++){
    Valor=Valor*Valor;
}
long B=System.currentTimeMillis();
String saludo = "El resultado es "+Valor+","+(A-B);
// envio el saludo al cliente
oos.writeObject(saludo);
System.out.println("Resultado enviado...");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
if( oos !=null ) oos.close();
if( ois !=null ) ois.close();
if( s != null ) s.close();
System.out.println("Conexion cerrada!");
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: If you are using VirtualBox or VMware, you can forward a port to your localhost.

Comment: This isn't really a Java question, though... It's more "how do you connect to a server running in a virtual machine". Programming language shouldn't really matter

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, it's just that I'm using Java so I thought I should add it in just in case.

Comment: No worries, just letting you know that the process shouldn't be any different for a different language if you've tried searching for a solution already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no different from connecting to a physical host. You need to have a network connection between the two machines - which is part of the virtual machine setup - and then specify the appropriate ip address (or hostname if available via name resolution mechanisms) and port instead of `127.0.0.1`.

For command line tools you commonly read the target address from a parameter.